# Error (403) when using UrlFetchApp to address an endpoint from https://discord.com

Tags: google-apps-script, discord, cloudflare, http-status-code-403

Discord recently announced that they move their API from discordapp.com to discord.com.

I'm in the midst of rewriting some code of mine (Google Apps Script project) to account for that, but I'm running into the problem of not being able to access the `discord.com`-endpoints, e.g.:

```js
function example(){
  var headers =
  {
    "Authorization": "Bot AbCdEfG123",
    "Accept": "*/*"
  };
  var options =
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": headers,
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://discord.com/api/guilds/"+GUILD_ID+"/members/"+MEMBER_ID, options);
}
```

even though using the old `discordapp.com` works perfectly fine.
Using `discord.com` results in a 403 error, with `error code 1020`.

Further investigation:

- Performing the same requests (against `discord.com`) via Postman or curl is successful, so it looks like the problem lies with UrlFetchApp
- By adding `"Accept": "*/*"` to the headers, I found out that the error comes from Cloudflare, along with the message `Please enable cookies`.
- Adding a User-Agent to the headers, e.g. `"User-Agent": "MyBot/1.0"` doesn't change anything

I have no idea how to deal with this and I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue. I'm grateful for any help.

**edit:**

Here's the requested documentation:

- Discord: https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference
- UrlFetchApp: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

The curl code that works is

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bot [...]" "https://discord.com/api/guilds/[...]/members/[...]"
```

with an ellipsis `[...]` representing the token or IDs

**edit 2:**

Google Apps Script uses the following unmodifiable user-agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: [...])
```

Even if I take only the Mozilla part into my curl command, i.e.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bot [...]" -H "user-agent: Mozilla" "https://discord.com/api/guilds/[...]/members/[...]"
```

I get the same `1020` error code.

Comment: [Edit] to Provide 1.Documentation link  and 2. Curl code

Comment: Did you miss the `Bot` and the space before the token in authorization header?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The `Bot ` is there, right where it belongs.

Comment: Apps script doesn't support User-Agent header.  But I'm not sure whether that is a problem. 403 could mean you missed the authorization header or missed `Bot `. Do [edit] your question code to make it clear that you use `Bot ` in the correct position. Also add `Accept:` headers in the code. `Please enable cookies.` would mean you're redirected from a error page to a html page.

Comment: Check whether your error code is from any of this: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes

Comment: Unfortunately, only the HTTP error code (403) is given on that page, which is too little information to work on.
I receive the exact same error (HTTP 403 with error code 1020 in the message) even if I use an invalid token, like "Bot abc".

Interestingly, using "discordapp.com" as base_url instead would give me a 401 Error when using "Bot abc". This is yet another example on how discordapp.com and discord.com behave differently.

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to user agent, in which case, there's nothing you can do. Try setting a explicit version in the api like v8

Comment: Based on your conjecture that it's due to user-agent, I just performed another test: I took Apps Script's user-agent and used it in my curl headers. I found that if the user-agent contains the text "Mozilla", e.g. `
curl -H "Authorization: Bot [...]" -H "user-agent: Mozilla" "https://discord.com/api/guilds/[...]/members/[...]"`, even curl will run into the same problem of mine. So indeed it seems like there's nothing I can do.

Comment: You can always contact discord with a link  to this question and explain your issue. They might be able to fix it.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the user agent per this format https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#user-agent

```
User-Agent: DiscordBot ($url, $versionNumber)
```