# HTTP Request to Discord API Through Google Apps Script Results in 403 Error With Response "Error Code 1020"

Tags: google-apps-script, discord, bots

I'm having trouble getting guild channels with this code in Google Apps Script.

```
var token = "MY_TOKEN"
var url = "https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/[GUILD_ID]/channels"
var header = {
  Authorization: "Bot " + token
}

function myFunction(){
  var params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: header,
    muteHttpExceptions: false
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params)
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
}
```

Running `myFunction()` results in this error message:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://discord.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: error code: 1020 (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

or just this if the `muteHttpExceptions` value is `true`:

```
error code: 1020
```

Some information that may be useful to diagnose my problem:

- My bot is in my server, but it's shown to be offline in the member list (does it matter?)
- My bot is a private bot
- I have made sure that the bot token and guild ID are correct
- I invited the bot to my server via a generated link in OAuth2 URL generator in Discord Developer Portal. I checked the `bot` scope only with administrator permission. (Additional info: The first time I tried generating URL, it didn't need a redirect URL. But for some reason, it requires me to select one from a dropdown list now, but when I click on the dropdown, the list is empty as shown in the screenshot, so I can't select one and can't generate URL from there anymore.)
  [image]
- Get Current User Guild (`/users/@me/guilds`) runs perfectly fine. It returns this array:

```
[
  {
    "id": "[GUILD_ID]",
    "name": "[GUILD_NAME]",
    "icon": null,
    "owner": false,
    "permissions": "4398046511103",
    "features": [
      "APPLICATION_COMMAND_PERMISSIONS_V2"
    ]
  }
]
```

I think my problem has something to do with the bot permissions, but I'm just lost.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this error can be traced back to Cloudfare. It appears that the Apps Script user-agent is unable to be altered, which leads to the blocking of the API call to Discord by using Bot token type.

See : [Error (403) when using UrlFetchApp to address an endpoint from https://discord.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64632916/error-403-when-using-urlfetchapp-to-address-an-endpoint-from-https-discord-c)